# Height of room with only surface area?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, estimation, volume

I have this problem where I am only given the surface area of a room (170 ft^2) and they want me to find the approximate value for volume.

They give me the following answer choices, which I converted to feet.

40m^3 -> 1384ft^3

4m^3 -> 138ft^3

16m^3 -> 553ft^3

400m^3 -> 13840ft^3

4000m^3 -> 138408ft^3

Now I used the volume formula v=(area)(height) and substituted a height I thought was reasonable, about 8ft.

1360ft^3 = (170ft^2)(8ft)

Would I be correct in saying that an approx. value of the volume is 40m^3?

I checked with a tutor and they suggested that 16m^3 would be more reasonable. But that would mean the height is around 3.5-4ft. Which... I don't think would be right? Any second opinions?

Comment: Look carefully at the question. You've misinterpreted it.

Answer (score 2):

For any given surface area, the greatest achievable volume will be if you use a sphere.

$SA_{sphere} = 4\pi R^{2}$

So, $R \approx 3.68 \text{ ft}$

$V_{sphere} = \frac{4}{3} \pi R^3 \approx 209 \text{ ft}^{3}$

The reason your answer is wrong is that $8 \text{ ft}$ is unreasonable for the size of the room.

The area of a square with $8 \text{ ft}$ sides is $64 \text{ ft}^{2}$. 
A cube is composed of $6$ sides, so this gives a surface area of $384 \text{ ft}^{2}$. Using $5 \text{ ft}$ would be much more reasonable.

Additionally, you multiply the surface area of the entire room (walls, ceiling, and floor) to get the volume. Instead, you should multiply the surface area of the floor of the room by the height.

The reason (I think) your tutor's answer is wrong is that they erroneously took your $8 \text{ ft}$ answer and worked with it. $(8 \text{ ft}) ^3 = 512 \text{ ft} ^3$

Comment: I accidentally down voted, and can't seem to change that.   Very sorry!  I think if you make any small edit I will be able to rescind the down vote.

Answer (score 1):

In your calculation, you seem to have assumed that the surface area given was the area of the floor. If the question worded it as you've presented here, then the surface area the question may be referring to is the area of each surface within the room: \begin{equation} Surface Area = 2*(length*width + length*height + width*height) = 170 ft^2\end{equation}

If we assume that the room is a perfect cube (which would be a fair assumption, given that the options differ by orders of magnitude), then the surface area equation becomes: \begin{equation} Surface Area = 6x^2 \end{equation}
where the length, width, and height all equal x. The volume of the cube room is then: \begin{equation} Volume = x^3 = \Bigl(\frac{Surface Area}{6}\Bigr)^{3/2} = \Bigl(\frac{170 ft^2}{6}\Bigr)^{3/2} \approx 150.8 ft^3\end{equation}

Since you already did the conversions for each of the options, you can see that the closest answer is 4m^3 which would make it the most reasonable choice.